# I need a help in creating a observable list with the result set?

Tags: java, javafx, resultset

I am sorry  I am newbie and I have this doubt... following is my query.

```
Select id,item_table.item_name,quantity,
total from Sales
inner join item_table on item_code=id
```

I take values from two different tables and I need to create an `ObservableList` with the `ResultSet` to load into `TableView` with columns id, name, quantity, sales?

I have two classes:

1. sales with field id,quantity and total sales
2. item with item_name

Can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking, if it's possible to create a `TableView` with 4 columns and fill it with data? Of course!

Comment: I want to fill the table column with the resultset from the query I mentioned.

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/sedj601/SQLitePersonTableViewExample) helps.